# Selenium FullPage Screenshots .NET6

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

Previously we was using the below code to take FullPage Screenshots when running our tests:

```
VerticalCombineDecorator vcs = new VerticalCombineDecorator(new ScreenshotMaker());
_driver.TakeScreenshot(vcs).ToMagickImage().Write(Path, MagickFormat.Png);
```

This used a package called Noksa.WebDriver.ScreenshotExtentions, however, this now has a dependency on Magick.NET-Q8-AnyCPU 7.9.0 which has a flag on for vulnerabilities so we cannot use Noksa due to its dependency showing a vulnerabilities on our NuGet package scanner.

How are people taking full page screenshots in .NET6? We use them on our reports, we can do viewport but Full Page is better for us.

Thanks

I have tried using multiple options that I have seen online but most arent supported in .NET 6

Comment: Why are you not using the `GetScreenshot()` method provided by `ITakesScreenshot` ?

Comment: GetScreenshot() only takes a screenshot of the active window, even if the page is bigger than the "viewport" therefore GetScreenshot doesnt help if we are at the bottom of a page and an error is at the top where we would need to scroll